# lucene java11 WARNING?

Tags: lucene, warnings, java-11, illegalaccessexception

I have this really simple java Lucene code that works in my friends PC but it makes a lot of errors for me ... we all use Lucene 5.3.1, I think that the problem is my jdk11

```
package project;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.IntField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
public class Act1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws
IOException {
Document doc = new Document();
Field titre = new TextField("Titre", "mon A staticestimation technique",Field.Store.YES);
Field ref = new IntField("Year", 2001,Field.Store.YES);
Field auteurs = new TextField("Auteurs","TaewhanKim, Ki-Seok Chung, C. L. Liu",Field.Store.YES);
doc.add(titre);
doc.add(ref);
doc.add(auteurs);
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\abc");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(p);
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
IndexWriter index = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
index.addDocument(doc);
index.close();
}
}
```

but it make those errors

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$1 (file:/C:/Users/user/Downloads/lucene-5.3.1/core/lucene-core-5.3.1.jar) to method java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.cleaner()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to unmap the mapped buffer: MMapIndexInput(path="C:\Users\user\Desktop\abc\_1_Lucene50_0.doc")
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2.freeBuffer(MMapDirectory.java:329)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.freeBuffer(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:376)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.close(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:355)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50CompoundFormat.write(Lucene50CompoundFormat.java:92)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.createCompoundFile(IndexWriter.java:4680)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.sealFlushedSegment(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:492)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:459)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:503)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:615)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3121)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3096)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.shutdown(IndexWriter.java:1078)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1123)
    at projet.Act1.main(Act1.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1 cannot access class jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.ref to unnamed module @6e8dacdf
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:322)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:314)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2.freeBuffer(MMapDirectory.java:314)
    ... 13 more
```

please help me to fix this problem ... 
 and plz if there is anyone who is good in java and Lucene help I'm struggling I have a mini java/Lucene project and because  of covid19 we didn't had any course... as you can see I can't even write a simple code

Comment: Short answer is: Yes it's the Java version. With Oracle's Java 8 that specific issue does not happen. With AdoptOpenJDK 11, for example, it does. Are you obliged to use such an old version of Lucene? I think 5.3.1 is about 5 years old.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials you can refer to, if you do some web research. I do not use version 5.x. My Lucene code (for version 8.x) typically will not work for that older version, because of changes to Lucene over the last 5 years. Do your research, then write some code. And if you have a _specific_ problem, you can ask a new _specific_ question on this site (assuming it has not already been asked and answered).

Comment: YES I have to, unfortunately... I didn't find any good source of information I will be so grateful if you can help me or give me any advice on how to search after creating an index (sorry for my English by the hey haha)

Comment: okey i will try thnx